# Can you use PRAW to find someone's first comment in a subreddit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

It looks like there's no way to get the date a user subscribed to a subreddit through PRAW, but is there a way to get a user's first comment in a particular subreddit?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of doing it is by parsing all his comments and filtering out those comments made on that specific subreddit. You can then sort that list based on `comment.created_utc` and get the oldest comment.

You can parse all the comments of a user and filter comments from a specific subreddit like so -

```
user = reddit.redditor('username')
target_subreddit = 'target_subreddit'
comment_list = []
# This iterates over all the comments made by the user
for comment in user.comments.new(limit=None):
    # Check if a comment belongs to your target subreddit
    if str(comment.subreddit) == target_subreddit:
        comment_list.append(comment)

# Sort comment_list based on comment.created_utc to get the oldest comment
...
```

Comment: Thank you! I know this must be a simple step, but I'm also really struggling to figure out how to filter a user's comments by subreddit. Any advice?